# wxpython: popup window upon tree item activated goes behind

Tags: wxpython

I am creating a showing a frame upon double clicking and thus activating a tree item( EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED). Popup window first appears in front and then goes behind the main window. How can I keep it front and restrict it from going it back?
Thanks in advance for for any help. 
By the way, I already tried Raise() and Iconize(False) but no help. I am wondering if the double clicking is causing the problem ( but that's the only way to activate tree item). I am feeling this because I have another popup window  attached to button and creates popup window upon single clicking a button.  When I double click the button two popup window appears, one in front of main window and other in behind of main window. 
Can anyone explain why that's happening?

Comment: If you can, post some simplified code to demonstrate the problem.  The enter and space keys should trigger the same event for the selected tree item.  What happens when you use those?

Comment: In my case space key does not do anything and Enter key raise an exception. Anyway, I changed the binding for all popup window  from EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED to EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED. In my opinion, pop up window with EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED is not a good idea. Thanks for the help.